# Dimple.js Candlestick Chart

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am using Dimple.js to plot several data series and I need to add a candlestick or hi/lo series on to my existing chart.  After some analysis, I have found two possible approaches to do this:

1)  Use the floating bar option in Dimple.js.  Since the "widths" (heights on the chart, but widths for the floating bar) would be all different, I would need a different data series for each candlestick.  This feels like a hack, but the one advantage is that this would be using Dimple to do all the rendering.  I would probably not go this route unless some had a thought on how to make this less of a hack.

2)  Drop down to D3 to draw lines between the points.  I can use Dimple.js to graph both the top and bottom elements of the candlestick, then use D3 to draw the line between the points.  I would do a selectAll() on one of the series, and then draw a path to the related point in the other series.

If there are other suggestions on an approach, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have tried another approach which seems reasonably effective.  I create a new series for each hi/lo combination and plot it as a Dimple line.  One trick--you need to increment the x-value of the hi or lo value so the two x's are not the same.  I suspect this is because a proper function f(x) cannot have any x-value such that f(x) will produce to different y's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/abeppu/1074045) to build candlestick charts using d3.js